# Error in calculating state density "dens"

Tags: quantum-espresso, density-of-states

I'm trying to tracking the state density of a system using Quantum Espresso by running this input file:

```
&system
    ibrav=4, celldm(1) =10.410909236, 
    nat=20, ntyp=1,
    ecutwfc=2.50000e+01
    ecutrho=2.25000e+02
    nbnd=84
/
&electrons
    conv_thr=1.00000e-06
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
Si     28.08550  Si.pbe-n-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
Ca     40.07800  Ca.pbe-spn-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
P      30.97376  P.pbe-n-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
O      15.99940  O.pbe-n-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF

ATOMIC_POSITIONS (alat)
Si            0.0000000000        0.0000000000       -0.0157540426
O             0.3299136474        0.0545324986        0.0595401725
O             0.9454675014        0.2753811489        0.0595401725
O             0.7246188511        0.6700863526        0.0595401725
P             0.6666670000        0.3333330000        0.0987976560
O             0.6666670000        0.3333330000        0.2113501434
Ca            0.6666670000        0.3333330000        0.3706146451
O             0.1992673103       -0.1108239995        0.4380418511
O             1.1108239995        0.3100913098        0.4380418511
O             0.6899086902        0.8007326897        0.4380418511
Si           -0.0000000000       -0.0000000000        0.5320360071
O             0.2891646956        0.3289811702        0.6093561073
O             0.0398164747        0.7108353044        0.6093561073
O             0.6710188298        0.9601835253        0.6093561073
P             0.3333330000        0.6666670000        0.6406709519
O             0.3333330000        0.6666670000        0.7561974923
P             0.3333330000        0.6666670000        0.8748653332
O             0.2739498732        0.3264620877        0.9034691403
O             0.0525122146        0.7260501268        0.9034691403
O             0.6735379123        0.9474877854        0.9034691403
K_POINTS {crystal_b}
12
20 !Gamma
20 !M
20 !K
20 !Gamma
20 !A
20 !L
20 !H
0  !A
20 !L
0  !M
20 !K
```

However, I get this error message:

```
[[49511,1],0]: A high-performance Open MPI point-to-point messaging module
was unable to find any relevant network interfaces:

Module: OpenFabrics (openib)
  Host: quantum2

Another transport will be used instead, although this may result in
lower performance.

NOTE: You can disable this warning by setting the MCA parameter
btl_base_warn_component_unused to 0.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

     Program BANDS v.6.5 starts on  5Sep2023 at 15:16:19 

     This program is part of the open-source Quantum ESPRESSO suite
     for quantum simulation of materials; please cite
         "P. Giannozzi et al., J. Phys.:Condens. Matter 21 395502 (2009);
         "P. Giannozzi et al., J. Phys.:Condens. Matter 29 465901 (2017);
          URL http://www.quantum-espresso.org", 
     in publications or presentations arising from this work. More details at
     http://www.quantum-espresso.org/quote

     Parallel version (MPI & OpenMP), running on      32 processor cores
     Number of MPI processes:                 1
     Threads/MPI process:                    32

     MPI processes distributed on     1 nodes

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     Error in routine bands (1):
     reading bands namelist
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

     stopping ...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank 0 in communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
with errorcode 1.

NOTE: invoking MPI_ABORT causes Open MPI to kill all MPI processes.
You may or may not see output from other processes, depending on
exactly when Open MPI kills them.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone help me to know what I did wrong in the input file?

Comment: This is all but unreadable - could you try to format it a bit better please?

Comment: Welcome to the site! In the future, you can code blocks (three backticks `\`` enclosing the content) to format code or program input/output files.

Comment: The input file you attached is for an `scf (pw.x)` calculation. The error output you received is for a `pp (bands.x)` calculation. So, I guess you are using incorrect input to your `bands.x` run or you are incorrectly executing your `scf (pw.x)` run. Could you add how you executed the program and what is your goal?